# UITableView count not increasing

Tags: iphone, uitableview, count, uitextview, nsuserdefaults

I have UITextView in ViewController. Im passing the textView to viewcontroller1 UITableView. I used NSUserDefaults for store and retrieve text. In viewcontroller1 UITebleView is not increasing with updating text, it replacing old text in only first row.

viewController:

```
-(void)save:(id)sender{

     NSUserDefaults *userData1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userData1 setObject:textView.text forKey:@"savetext"];
    [userData1 synchronize];
}
```

ViewController1:

```
     -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

            [super viewWillAppear:animated];

            textArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];    

            txt=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // getting an NSString

    NSString *savedValue = [prefs stringForKey:@"savetext"];

    txt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", savedValue];

    MyAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


   // [MyAppDelegate.textArray addObject:txt.text];

       if(![MyAppDelegate.textArray containsObject:txt.text]){
        [MyAppDelegate.textArray addObject:txt.text];
    }

    NSUserDefaults *userData1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userData1 setObject:MyAppDelegate.textArray forKey:@"save"];
    [userData1 synchronize];

    [self.view addSubview:txt];


        }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


  //  NSLog(@"textArray count is %d",[MyAppDelegate.textArray count]);

    NSMutableArray* myMutableArrayAgain = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"save"]];

    return [myMutableArrayAgain count];

}




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    NSMutableArray* myMutableArrayAgain = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"save"]];


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [myMutableArrayAgain objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:14]];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: pls enter the text array count u got from nslog

Comment: and code for storing text to NSUserdefaults.

Comment: I didn't get textArray count in nslog...

Comment: Please write `return [textArray count];` after `NSLog()`. and show the log

Comment: always textArray count is 1

Comment: @user2807197 : Please Check you have linked tableview in interface builder.

Comment: I didn't use interface builder

Comment: make textArray in appdelegate it will work.in this current code textArray every time initialise and only add one object

Comment: @pratikbhiyani: textArray appdelegate means? how?

Comment: declare your textArray in appdelegate.h file and alloc/init in appdelegate.m file and than access it from ViewController1.m

Comment: I didn't get how to write? can you show some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare your array object in your `Appdelegate.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSMutableArray *textArray;
```

allocate this array object in your `Appdelegate.m` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"save"]];
if(array)
{
self.textArray = array;
}
else
{
        self.textArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];    
}
```

import `Appdelegate.h` file in `ViewController1.h` and declare this

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate;
```

change following method in your code in `ViewController1.m` file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

 tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)                                           style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        NSLog(@"Scrolling");

        tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

        //  tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0,300, 0); //values passed are - top, left, bottom, right
        tableView.delegate = self;
        tableView.dataSource = self;
        [tableView reloadData];

        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0,300, 0);


        //self.view = tableView;
        [self.view addSubview:tableView];


}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        // getting an NSString

        NSString *savedValue = [prefs stringForKey:@"savetext"];    

        txt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", savedValue];

        appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
         if(![appdelegate.textArray containsObject:savedValue]){
             [appdelegate.textArray addObject:savedValue];
         }




    }
```

change following 2 methods

```
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return [appdelegate.textArray count];

        NSLog(@"textArray count is %d",[textArray count]);
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        }
        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel.text = [appdelegate.textArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:14]];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your requirement. You want to add objects to an existing array when the viewWillAppear. But you are initializing the array whenever *viewWillAppear* invoked. Thats why you get only one object at every time. For this purpose you have to maintain a singleton class and add object to the array in viewWillAppear.

You have to take a look on this:

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Answer (score 0):

Just alloc yourarray  and table in `ViewDidLoad` rather then `ViewWillAppear`

```
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)                                           style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    textArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```